# kendo datepicker javascript files

Tags: javascript, datepicker, kendo-ui

I am having only datepicker component on my page.

I have to include - `kendo.all.min.js` file
that's huge (800KB)

Can I do something about the size? In the js directory of kendo I can see many js files such as kendo.datepicker.js, kendo.core.js etc but any combination did not worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information that you need is in [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/javascript-dependencies#datepicker):

DatePicker

1. jquery-1.9.1.js
2. kendo.core.js
3. kendo.fx.js (optional for animation)
4. kendo.popup.js
5. kendo.calendar.js
6. kendo.datepicker.js